# How do you display XML code in HTML

Tags: html, xml, web

What I'm trying to figure out is how to display `XML` snippets on a webpage using `HTML`. However the things I've tried have resulted in my `XML` tags to disappear but the text remains.

```
<pre> <code class="codeblock"><![CDATA[
   <dependency>
     <groupId>com.foo.bar</groupId>
     <artifactId>bar</artifactId>
     <version>LATEST</version>
   </dependency>
]]></code></pre>
```

The above results in the below to be displayed

```
com.foo.bar
bar
LATEST
```

the desired output would be

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.foo.bar</groupId>
  <artifactId>bar</artifactId>
  <version>LATEST</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: @MelanciaUK thanks seemed to have missed that when searching

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
<pre>&lt;dependency&gt;
  &lt;groupId&gt;com.foo.bar&lt;/groupId&gt;
  &lt;artifactId&gt;bar&lt;/artifactId&gt;
  &lt;version&gt;LATEST&lt;/version&gt;
&lt;/dependency&gt;</pre>
```